# Setting up WebSphere MQ integration in a WebLogic clustered environment

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, ibm-mq

I have a WebLogic cluster up and running an application containing an MDB. I'm currently using WebLogic JMS queues to send messages to the MDB. All is well.

I now have need to switch to IBM WebSphere MQ for my JMS messaging.

I can set this up and send/receive messages in a non-clustered environment (Admin server) using a Foreign server with a bindings file. However, I can't seem to properly configure the clustered environment for MQ integration to work correctly.

I get the following when deploying the EAR/MDB on the cluster:

```
The Message-Driven EJB: xxxMDB is unable to connect to the JMS destination...
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'jms.xxxQueue'
```

Can anyone point me to some documentation on how to configure IBM WebSphere MQ in a WebLogic cluster?

Thanks!

Comment: If the error were in MQ I might be able to help but it looks like the JNDI lookup is what is failing. I found a rather old whitepaper here ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/service-bus/overview/osb-websphere-whitepaper-132660.pdf ) that *might* help. Also, if you find any references to the MQ Transactional client bearing a license cost, that is no longer true as of today as per http://ibm.co/WMQ75Announce

Answer (score 0):

there is a need to add several MQ JMS classes to the PATH of the weblogic so it will be able to connect to MQ 
the path needed to be added is : *MQ_system_path*/java/lib64
beside that here are the clasess i have found that are needed to make this thing :
com.ibm.mq.mqi.jar; com.ibm.mq.headers.jar; com.ibm.mq.jar; commonservices.jar; com.ibm.mq.jms.jar;jta.jar;

this what helped us to connect weblogic to MQ

regards

Oren yeger